# Incorporating Two Buttons for PHP Form. Submit succeed but Update button prompt error

Tags: php, html

I have two buttons that served my PHP form which is the Update and the Submit button. Right now, the problem is on the Update Button. Sorry for asking something that might feels like a silly question but I have problem with making my update button worked. When I clicked on the update button it will return error like this

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\dataentry\user\edit_draft.php on line 241

Line 241 is

> $sql ="SELECT *FROM iir_incidentmain_draft WHERE incident_id='$_GET[id]'";

I didn't know what is wrong since the code I  made is actually the same as the submit report but not working for updating. Below is the three related pages of my codes.

draft.php

```
<div class="col-md-9 bg-white padding-2">

  <h3>Reports in Draft</h3>
  <div class="row margin-top-20">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <th>Incident Date</th>
            <th>OPU Region Or Country</th>
            <th>Incident Title</th>
            <th>Incident Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Draft IIR</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM iir_incidentmain_draft WHERE username='" . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . "'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //If Job Post exists then display details of post
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <?php echo date("y-m-d", strtotime($row['incident_date'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['opus']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['incident_title']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['incident_category']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['status']; ?>
                </td>
                <td><a href="iir_draft.php?id=<?php echo $row['incident_id']; ?>">&nbsp; &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href="edit_draft.php?id=<?php echo $row['incident_id']; ?>">&nbsp; &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and this one the edit_draft.php (long form containing two buttons. I already shortened it)

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
<?php
    $sql ="SELECT *FROM iir_incidentmain_draft WHERE incident_id='$_GET[id]'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="incident_title" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Incident Title : <font color="red">*</font></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" id="incident_title" name="incident_title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row1['incident_title']; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="incident_description" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Incident Description : <font color="red">*</font></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="incident_description" name="incident_description" class="form-control" placeholder="(What, When, Where, Why, How?) (Explain in full including dates, location, cause and action)"><?php echo $row1['incident_description']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="incident_description" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Witness : </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <textarea rows="2" cols="50" id="witness" name="witness" class="form-control"><?php echo $row1['witness']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <--some more details->

        <div align="right" class="bottom">
          <button type="update" class="btn btn-dark" id="update" formaction="update_draft.php">Update Draft</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit Report</button>
        </div>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</form>
```

and here the update_draft.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header ("Location:../index.php");
    exit();
}

require_once("db.php");

if (isset($_GET['idpost']) && is_numeric($_GET['idpost'])) {

    $incident_id = $_POST['idpost'];
    $username= $_SESSION['user']['username'];
    $incident_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_title']);
    $incident_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_description']);
    $witness = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['witness']);
    $incident_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_date']);
    $incident_year =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_year']);
    $incident_month = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_month']);
    $monsoon = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['monsoon']);
    $holiday = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['holiday']);
    $incident_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_time']);
    $time_hourly = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time_hourly']);
    $time_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time_category']);
    $incident_location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_location']);
    $latitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['latitude']);
    $longitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['longitude']);
    $incident_worksite = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_worksite']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['state']);  
    $onshoreoffshore = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['onshoreoffshore']);
    $vessel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['vessel']);
    $incident_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_type']);
    $incident_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incident_category']);
    $accident_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['accident_type']);
    $day_lost_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['daylosttime']);
    $estimated_cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['estimatedcost']);
    $actual_cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['actualcost']);
    $spill_voll = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['spillvolume']);
    $production_loss = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['productionloss']);
    if($_POST['productionunit']=="OTHER") {
        $production_unit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['productionunit2a']);
    } else {
        $production_unit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['productionunit']);
    }
    $downtime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['downtime']);
    $impact_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['impactto']);
    $sector = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sector']);
    $department = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['department']);
    $business_group = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['business_group']);  
    $business_section = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['business_section']);
    $opus = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['opus']);  
    $domestic_international = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_name']);
    $project_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_name']);
    $project_phase = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_phase']);
    $project_start_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_start_date']);
    $project_end_date= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_end_date']);
    $project_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_type']);

    if($_POST['contractor']=="ifothers") {
        $contractor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contractor2']);
    } else {
        $contractor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contractor']);
    }

    $sub_contractor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sub_contractor']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['injuriousname']);
    $staff_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['staff_no']);
    $staff_department = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['staff_department']);
    $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nationality']);
    $age_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['age']);
    $age_range = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['agerange']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
    $work_trade = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['worktrades']);
    $years_of_experience = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['yearsexp']);
    $imm_supervisor_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['supervisor']);
    $desc_of_injury = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['injuries_description']);
    $body_part = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bodypart']);
    $body_part_group = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bodypartgroup']);
    $hours_in_shift = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hoursinshift']);
    $days_in_tour = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['daysintour']);
    $hse_risk = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hserisks']);
    $critical_activity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['critical_activity']);
    $sub_critical = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sub_activity']);
    $hazard = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hazard']);
    $hazard_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hazardnumber']);
    $sub_hazard = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subhazard']);
    $sub_hazard_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subhazardnumber']);
    $failed_missing_barrier = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['barrier']);
    $ic_description1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description1']);
    $precondition1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['precondition1']);
    $uauc1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uauc1']);
    $root_cause_latern_failure1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description1']);
    $brf1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['riskfactor1']);
    $ic_description2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description2']);
    $precondition2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['precondition2']);
    $uauc2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uauc2']);
    $root_cause_latern_failure2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description2']);
    $brf2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['riskfactor2']);
    $ic_description3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description3']);
    $precondition3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['precondition3']);
    $uauc3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uauc3']);
    $root_cause_latern_failure3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description3']);
    $brf3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['riskfactor3']);
    $ic_description4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description4']);
    $precondition4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['precondition4']);
    $uauc4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uauc4']);
    $root_cause_latern_failure4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ic_description4']);
    $brf4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['riskfactor4']);
    $immediateaction = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['immediateaction']);
    $person_responsible = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['person_responsible']);
    $completion_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['completion_date']);
    $permanentaction = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['permanentaction']);
    $person_responsible1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['person_responsible1']);
    $completion_date1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['completion_date1']);
    $managementaction = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['managementaction']);
    $person_responsible2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['person_responsible2']);
    $completion_date2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['completion_date2']);
    $ratingperson = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ratingperson']);
    $ratingenvironment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ratingenvironment']);
    $ratingasset = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ratingasset']);
    $ratingreputation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ratingreputation']);
    $ratingsecurity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ratingsecurity']);
    $report_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['report_status']);

    $file = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    for( $i=0 ; $i < $file ; $i++ ){
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
            $newFilePath = "../uploads/attachment/report" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                echo "Uploads success";
            }   else {
                echo "Failed to upload";
                //header ("Location: newentry.php");
                exit();
            } 
        }
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE iir_incidentmain_draft 
            SET incident_title = '".$incident_title."', 
                incident_description = '".$incident_description."', 
                witness = '".$witness."', 
                incident_date = '".$incident_date."', 
                incident_year ='".$incident_year."', 
                incident_month = '".$incident_month."', 
                monsoon ='".$monsoon."', 
                holiday = '".$holiday."', 
                incident_time = '".$incident_time."', 
                time_hourly = '".$time_hourly."', 
                time_category = '".$time_category."', 
                incident_location = '".$incident_location."', 
                latitude = '".$latitude."', 
                longitude = '".$longitude."', 
                incident_worksite = '".$incident_worksite."', 
                country = '".$country."', 
                state = '".$state."', 
                onshoreoffshore = '".$onshoreoffshore."', 
                vessel = '".$vessel."', 
                incident_type = '".$incident_type."', 
                incident_category = '".$incident_category."', 
                accident_type = '".$accident_type."', 
                day_lost_time = '".$day_lost_time."', 
                estimated_cost'".$estimated_cost."', 
                actual_cost='".$actual_cost."', 
                spill_voll='".$spill_voll."', 
                production_loss='".$production_loss."', 
                production_unit='".$production_unit."', 
                downtime='".$downtime."', 
                impact_to='".$impact_to."', 
                sector='".$sector."', 
                department='".$department."', 
                business_group='".$business_group."', 
                business_section='".$business_section."', 
                opus='".$opus."', 
                domestic_international = '".$domestic_international."', 
                project_name = '".$project_name."', 
                project_phase = '".$project_phase."', 
                project_start_date = '".$project_start_date."', 
                project_end_date = '".$project_end_date."', 
                project_type = '".$project_type."', 
                contractor = '".$contractor."', 
                sub_contractor = '".$sub_contractor."', 
                name = '".$name."', 
                staff_no = '".$staff_no."', 
                staff_department = '".$staff_department."', 
                nationality = '".$nationality."', 
                age_number = '".$age_number."', 
                age_range = '".$age_range."', 
                gender = '".$gender."', 
                work_trade = '".$work_trade."', 
                years_of_experience = '".$years_of_experience."', 
                imm_supervisor_name = '".$imm_supervisor_name."', 
                desc_of_injury = '".$desc_of_injury."', 
                body_part = '".$body_part."', 
                body_part_group = '".$body_part_group."', 
                hours_in_shift = '".$hours_in_shift."', 
                days_in_tour = '".$days_in_tour."', 
                hse_risk = '".$hse_risk."', 
                critical_activity = '".$critical_activity."', 
                sub_critical = '".$sub_critical."', 
                hazard = '".$hazard."', 
                hazard_number = '".$hazard_number."', 
                sub_hazard = '".$sub_hazard."', 
                sub_hazard_no = '".$sub_hazard_no."', 
                failed_missing_barrier = '".$failed_missing_barrier."', 
                ic_description1 = '".$ic_description1."',
                precondition1 = '".$precondition1."', 
                uauc1='".$uauc1."', root_cause_latern_failure1 = '".$root_cause_latern_failure1."', 
                brf1 = '".$brf1."', 
                ic_description2 = '".$ic_description2."', 
                precondition2 = '".$precondition2."', 
                uauc2 = '".$uauc2."', 
                root_cause_latern_failure2 = '".$root_cause_latern_failure2."', 
                brf2 = '".$brf2."', 
                ic_description3 = '".$ic_description3."',  
                precondition3 = '".$precondition3."', 
                uauc3 = '".$uauc3."', 
                root_cause_latern_failure3 = '".$root_cause_latern_failure3."', 
                brf3 = '".$brf3."', 
                ic_description4 = '".$ic_description4."', 
                precondition4 = '".$precondition4."', 
                uauc4 = '".$uauc4."', 
                root_cause_latern_failure4 = '".$root_cause_latern_failure4."', 
                brf4 = '".$brf4."', 
                immediateaction = '".$immediateaction."', 
                person_responsible = '".$person_responsible."', 
                completion_date = '".$completion_date."', 
                permanentaction = '".$permanentaction."', 
                person_responsible1 ='".$person_responsible1."', 
                completion_date1 = '".$completion_date1."', 
                managementaction = '".$managementaction."', 
                person_responsible2 = '".$person_responsible2."', 
                completion_date2 = '".$completion_date2."', 
                ratingperson = '".$ratingperson."', 
                ratingenvironment = '".$ratingenvironment."', 
                ratingasset = '".$ratingasset."', 
                ratingreputation = '".$ratingreputation."', 
                ratingsecurity = '".$ratingsecurity."', 
                report_status = '".$report_status."', 
                file = '".$file."' 
        WHERE incident_id = '".$id."'"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 

    if(!$result)    { 
        die('Could not update data: '.  mysqli_error()); 
        header("Location: edit_draft.php");
        exit();
    } else { 
        $_SESSION['DraftEditSuccess'] = true;
        header("Location: draft.php");
        exit();
    } 
} else {
    header("Location:edit_draft.php");
    exit();
}


?>
```

I have tried multiple solution as suggested by 
[One form two buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116052/one-form-two-button)
[Two Submits Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790735/two-submit-buttons-for-one-form)
 and many more but it's not working. I hope there's someone that can guide me on this and I'm sorry for I'm still learning.

Comment: @CarlBinalla the error is on this part $sql ="SELECT *FROM iir_incidentmain_draft WHERE incident_id='$_GET[id]'";

Comment: @WanHazyan Are you opening `edit_draft.php` instead of redirecting from `draft.php

`?

Comment: Try this `$get =$_GET['id']; if(empty($get)){ echo "ID is empty";}`

Comment: Supposedly get the wanted report part from draft.php to open the form for edit_draft.php, if success, redirect to draft.php, if failed back to edit_draft.php

Comment: Try changing `$_GET['id']` to `{$_GET['id']}`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Do you get this error if you run `edit_draft.php?id=xx` where `xx` is a valid `incident_id` ???

Comment: @Dharman No. I read that but served no answer to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
if (isset($_GET['idpost']) && is_numeric($_GET['idpost']))
{
```

To

```
if (isset($_GET['idpost']) && is_numeric($_GET['idpost']))
{ $id = $_GET['idpost'];
```

This `$id` variable is not set in your whole codes `WHERE incident_id = '".$id."'";`

**UPDATE:**

I didnt see `$incident_id = $_POST['idpost'];` in your post.

Just change this

```
$incident_id = $_POST['idpost'];
```

To

```
$incident_id = $_GET['idpost'];
```

and this line in

```
WHERE incident_id = '".$id."'";`
```

to

```
WHERE incident_id = '$incident_id'";
```

Note : My first example will work fine is well.

You need to see this post for error reporting for mysqli [mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param/22662582#22662582)

Comment: So, where should I declare that part first? in my  update_draft.php or edit_draft.php?

Comment: `update_draft.php` and you need to pass id by url to `update_draft.php` looks like your id is empty try my comment under your question.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will try on this solution.

Comment: `edit_draft.php` does not have any reference to `$_GET['idpost']` So this will do NOTHING to help the actual problem in the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly My answer is about `update_draft.php` not for `edit_draft.php` I told OP to check if its empty in my comment under question! and yes, same in `edit_draft.php` too `incident_id='$_GET[id]'";` as I said in my earlier comment  *you need to pass id by url to `update_draft.php`* OP need to do that for `edit_draft.php` is well and I commented that under question asked to do if statement for id. So didnt want to repeat that in my answer again. My bad.

Comment: Ahh its always best to put everything in your answer. People only glance at comments when a Answer is there

Answer (score 2):

In the `update_draft.php` you redirect to `edit_draft.php` on updated failure, but when you do

```
header("Location: edit_draft.php");
```

you do not add an `id=something` parameter. Hence you get an error saying

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\dataentry\user\edit_draft.php on line 241

You dont show enough code for me to be sure what you should do, but either add an appropriate value to the redirect like

```
header("Location: edit_draft.php?id=$someRelevantValue");
```

Or you will have to modify the control code in `edit_draft.php` to be able to cope with the page being called Without an `id` present.

*To be honest I am not sure that going back to `edit_update.php` when the UPDATE of the database has failed is the best thing to do anyway*

Comment: So! all 3 answers are correct after your comment! your comment has nothing to do with `WHERE incident_id='$_GET[id]'";` in `edit_draft.php` or `WHERE incident_id = '".$incident_id."'";` in `update_draft.php` :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM iir_incidentmain_draft WHERE incident_id='$_GET[id]'";
```

to this:

```
$get=$_GET['idpost'];
$sql ="SELECT * FROM iir_incidentmain_draft WHERE incident_id='$get'";
```

As you can see, you wrong on `$_GET[id]` to `$_GET['idpost']`

Comment: @CarlBinalla I created the variable to highlight the error and make it more understandable

Comment: @Dilek why you say that?

Comment: becuase `$_GET['idpost']`

Comment: Changed with suggest